# Load XML file to MAUI project

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, maui

I am trying to load from XML file and parse it from Resources/Raw folder in project to MAUI app right at the beginning so that any class and screen can access this parsed XML file.

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiAppAsync()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });


        string path;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            path = await ReadResources();
            List<Siren> sirens = ParseXML(path);
        });        

        return builder.Build();
    }

    private static Task<string> ReadResources()
    {
        var stream = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("file.xml");
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream.Result);

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        });

        throw new FileLoadException();
    }
...
```

I have this line of code in my .csproj file
`<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\*" />` and in `App.xaml` I have this:

```
...
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Raw/file.xml" />
...
```

along with default fonts.

error of this program is:

```
Resource "Resources/Raw/file.xml" not found
```

I am new to MAUI and I need to know how to parse XML at the start of the app so that other classes can access parsed XML in array.

Comment: Can you give link(s) to the doc(s) or other resources that you are trying to follow, in writing this code? It doesn't look right, but I'm not sure exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include files from Resources/Raw I don't use ResourceDictionary, I just have the following in my .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

That copies all the files in the Raw directory (including folder structure beneath Raw) so I can access them using OpenAppPackageFileAsync. For some reason, however, occasionally there also ends up a line farther down in the .csproj with a Remove for specific files, like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiAsset Remove="Resources\Raw\file.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If I don't delete those I get a Resource not found error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this article about [How to deserialize xml document in C#](https://www.iditect.com/guide/csharp/csharp_howto_deserialize_xml_document.html).You will also find a lot of good resources in the Microsoft Documentation for C#. Since .NET MAUI uses .NET 6, you will find a significant level of compatibility with any code you find.You can check this article [How to load XML from a file (LINQ to XML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/load-xml-file) for a reference.